# Integrate Sublime Text 2 with Karma

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2, karma-runner

When doing AngularJS development, I have an open terminal window with Karma running (watching file changes). When coding I go back and forth between Sublime Text 2 and the terminal window showing Karma test results.

I find this pretty annoying and I just saw at `egghead.io` that this guy has Karma results integrated into WebStorm.

Is there anything similar for Sublime Text? I couldn't find any packages related to Karma.

Comment: I got here via egghead.io as well. I'm just waiting for some enterprising developer to add a Karma plugin. :)

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy The accepted answer is a good way to start, however didn't finish implementing myself as I switch from ST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a build system to kind of integrate the two--it opens the ST console and displays the results.

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
"build_systems": [
    {
        "name": "Karma Test",
        "cmd": ["karma", "start", "--no-colors"],
        "working_dir": "$project_path"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you do it yourself? If so, can you share the build configuration that you are using?

Comment: I did. I'll edit my answer when I find it again--I've switched back to using it from the command line again.

Comment: What plugins, extensions, or libraries did you use for your build system? Where would I add the build_systems data?

Comment: SublimeText3 can display colors if you add [SublimeANSI](https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI) plugin. That way instead of using ugly **dots** reporter you can use much nicer [spec reporter](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter)

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Tools | Build System | New Build System" and drop in the following code:

```
{
"path": "/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH",
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
"cmd": ["karma", "start"]
}
```

Can be found [here:](https://gist.github.com/rdodev/6283334).

Also this is [the best primer for setting up custom text build systems in sublime text](http://addyosmani.com/blog/custom-sublime-text-build-systems-for-popular-tools-and-languages/) that i've seen.

Cheers