# How to run a Unit Test in KARMA or MOCHA using User Interface?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, mocha.js, karma-runner, ui-automation

Am trying to figure out a way to run my test cases written in MOCHA or KARMA using an web User Interface. Am looking around web still i didn't get a proper way.

Comment: are you talking about real unit testing or ui automation? Those are different things.
Did you write test cases with protractor?

Comment: Ya i wrote using Protractor for e2e test. but i need to know is there any way to start the  test using custom user interface to interact with CLI by clicking a button.

Comment: the only way i've done this is with a Continuous Integration server like Jenkins or Bamboo

Comment: could you show some examples. thanks

Comment: sorry, I can't give you an example of this. Setting up a CI server is not something you do in a couple of hours. And it might be overkill for what you want to achieve.
[Here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrate Sublime Text 2 with Karma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877550/integrate-sublime-text-2-with-karma)